# Polymorphism issue with instantiating sub classes

Tags: c++, qt

I have an abstract base class `Company` and 2 sub classes `fProfit` and `Nfprofit` that derive from `Company` when I try to instantiate either of the sub classes I get the following error.

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test\nfprofit.cpp:19: error: prototype for 'QString Nfprofit::getName()' does not match any in class 'Nfprofit'
 QString Nfprofit::getName() {
         ^

C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test\nfprofit.h:17: error: candidate is: virtual QString Nfprofit::getName() const
     QString getName() const;
             ^
```

My headers for `Company` and `Nfprofit` are below.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

code:

```
class Company {
public:
virtual QString getName() const = 0;
virtual QString getDateFormed() const = 0;
virtual QString toString() const = 0;
};

class Nfprofit : public Company
{
public:
    Nfprofit(QString name, QString date, bool charitable);

    //setters
    void setName(QString name);
    void setDateFormed(QString date);
    void setCharitableStatus(bool charitable);

    //getters
    QString getName() const;
    QString getDateFormed() const;
    QString getCharitableStatus() const;

    QString toString() const;
private:
    QString m_name, m_dateFormed;
    bool m_charitable;
};
```

Comment: If you are using C++11, don't forget to also use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the error message is telling you:

Your member is a declared as `const`:

```
QString getName() const;
```

But your definition isn't `const`:

```
QString Nfprofit::getName() { .... }
```

You need to make it `const`:

```
QString Nfprofit::getName() const { .... }
                            ^^^^^
```

Comment: As an aside, I've always wondered why compilers cannot give a clearer error message for this case. Legions of beginners (including myself at the time when I learnt C++) must have been endlessly confused by this problem, wondering why the compiler denies an override and suggests, seemingly, exactly what you had told it in the first place.